# Getting object property value

Tags: javascript

My array is the following:

```
let arr = [
    {type: "Benzine", active: false},
    {type: "Diesel", active: false},
    {type: "Electricity", active: false}
]
```

And I have a function where I want to get value of the property `active` of that array:

```
function isChecked(filterName) {
    return arr.filter(f => f.type === filterName).map(c => c.active)[0];
}
```

That works fine, with `[0]` at the end. Is there any way to show the active property value without `[0]` at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as long as you use `filter`, there's not.
The `[0]` is used to get the first result from that filter.

Since you're just returning the value of `active`, you could use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), instead:

```js
let arr = [
  {type: "Benzine", active: false},
  {type: "Diesel", active: false},
  {type: "Electricity", active: true}
];

function isChecked(filterName){
  // Is there an element in the array that matches the filter AND is active?
  return arr.some(f => f.type === filterName && f.active);
}

console.log("Diesel:", isChecked("Diesel"));
console.log("Electricity:", isChecked("Electricity"));
```

Comment: Although this is a good example of a solution, ``some`` won't short circuit on first matching element, so in cases of "falsy" checked element, this will look through the whole array.

Comment: @mdziekon: Fair point, but looking at the contents of the array, I don't think that will be an issue. There aren't that many types of fuel out there.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `filter`, you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the first matching element of an array.

```
function isChecked(filterName) {
    var elem = arr.find(f => f.type === filterName);
    return elem ? elem.active : false;
}
```